# systemd-journald with volatile /var/log (poky)

Tags: systemd, yocto, systemd-journald

I'm trying to make my journal persistent.
Poky (yocto/krogoth) links `/var/log` to `/var/volatile/log` by default.
I've already removed this mount in `fstab` and replaced it with an `.mount` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Temporary Directory
Documentation=man:hier(7)
Documentation=http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=!/var/volatile
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target umount.target

[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/var/volatile
Type=tmpfs
Options=mode=1777,strictatime
```

And advised systemd-journald with the config file `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service.d/journald-volatile.conf` to require this mount file:

```
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=var-volatile.mount
```

Then I altered my `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf` to contain the lines:

```
D /var/log 0755 - - -
f /var/log/wtmp 0664 root utmp -
f /var/log/btmp 0600 root utmp -
# persist journal
L+ /var/log/journal 0666 root root - /opt/ttc/log/journal
```

This way, the `/var/log` is still volatile but `/var/log/journal` is linked to `/opt/ttc/log/journal` which should persist the journal.

However, this won't work. Even when I configure systemd-journald to be persistent it's writing to `/run/log/journal` and only starts writing to `/opt/ttc/log/journal` when I restart the systemd-journald.

After reboot, systemd-journald writes to `/run/log/journal` again.

Do I have to enable something different? Why won't systemd-journald write the journal to my path after boot, but does it when I restart the service?

Comment: Have you set the persistent flag in /etc/systemd/journald.conf?

Comment: @RamanSailopal >Even when I configure systemd-journald to be persistent

Comment: Can you update the question with the content of `cat /etc/systemd/journald.conf` on your built image?